# When I change PHP mailer subject it shows a warning on the avatar

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I am trying to send an email with PHPMailer library but when I change the subject from "PHPMailer SMTP test" the email will be sent but it will show a warning on the avatar as shown in the image.

I am defining the subject $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: add a screenshot of the avatar when the subject is 'PHPMailer SMTP test.

Comment: I would say try to use an appropriate subject....

Comment: here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3kDB.png

Comment: @Jagadeesh screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3kDB.png

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have tried several

Comment: exclude test from subject, write a good html email with a good subject and send from email which you are using as user...

Comment: @PraveenKumar still no luck

Comment: @PraveenKumar I changed subject and body and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One effective way to remove the warning sign is through authentication. Since you are using PHP-Mailer you can enable DKIM authentication for each mail sent from your domain.